# Highlighting a particular data column in a table using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to highlight a particular data field in a particular column in a normal html table using Jquery.Can you please provide a snippet of code for this scenario.What I have achieved is highlighting of the record for Solr but do not know how to apply it to a exact column in a row.

```
    var newresult = {"_header": {
        "nvPairs": [
                    "status",
                    0,
                    "QTime",
                    3,
                    "params",
                    {
                        "nvPairs": [
                            "hl.fragsize",
                            "100000",
                            "hl.simple.pre",
                            "<em>",
                            "hl.fl",
                            "name",
                            "wt",
                            "javabin",
                            "hl.maxAnalyzedChars",
                            "100000",
                            "hl",
                            "true",
                            "version",
                            "2",
                            "hl.highlightMultiTerm",
                            "true",
                            "hl.snippets",
                            "100",
                            "hl.useFastVectorHighlighter",
                            "true",
                            "q",
                            "harsha",
                            "hl.regex.slop",
                            "0.5",
                            "hl.regex.pattern",
                            "[-\\w ,/\n\\\"']*",
                            "hl.simple.post",
                            "</em>"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "_results": [
                {
                    "id": "21",
                    "name": [
                        "asd asda fsdfsdfds harsha sadaks asdasd sad fsddsf dsfdsf dsf sdf dsdsf sdfdsf dsfdsf dsf fdsdfsd fdsfdsf dfdsfdsfds  dsfsdf d f ds fdf df df dsfdsf dfdsf d      fdsdf dfs harsha"
                    ],
                    "_version_": 1508203924863058000
                }
            ],
            "_highlightingInfo": {
                "nvPairs": [
                    "21",
                    {
                        "nvPairs": [
                            "name",
                            [
                                "asd asda fsdfsdfds <em>harsha</em> sadaks asdasd sad fsddsf dsfdsf dsf sdf dsdsf sdfdsf dsfdsf dsf fdsdfsd fdsfdsf dfdsfdsfds  dsfsdf d f ds fdf df df dsfdsf dfdsf d      fdsdf dfs <em>harsha</em>"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "_highlighting": {
                "21": {
                    "name": [
                        "asd asda fsdfsdfds <em>harsha</em> sadaks asdasd sad fsddsf dsfdsf dsf sdf dsdsf sdfdsf dsfdsf dsf fdsdfsd fdsfdsf dfdsfdsfds  dsfsdf d f ds fdf df df dsfdsf dfdsf d      fdsdf dfs <em>harsha</em>"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "elapsedTime": 19,
            "response": {
                "nvPairs": [
                    "responseHeader",
                    {
                        "nvPairs": [
                            "status",
                            0,
                            "QTime",
                            3,
                            "params",
                            {
                                "nvPairs": [
                                    "hl.fragsize",
                                    "100000",
                                    "hl.simple.pre",
                                    "<em>",
                                    "hl.fl",
                                    "name",
                                    "wt",
                                    "javabin",
                                    "hl.maxAnalyzedChars",
                                    "100000",
                                    "hl",
                                    "true",
                                    "version",
                                    "2",
                                    "hl.highlightMultiTerm",
                                    "true",
                                    "hl.snippets",
                                    "100",
                                    "hl.useFastVectorHighlighter",
                                    "true",
                                    "q",
                                    "harsha",
                                    "hl.regex.slop",
                                    "0.5",
                                    "hl.regex.pattern",
                                    "[-\\w ,/\n\\\"']*",
                                    "hl.simple.post",
                                    "</em>"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "response",
                    [
                        {
                            "id": "21",
                            "name": [
                                "asd asda fsdfsdfds harsha sadaks asdasd sad fsddsf dsfdsf dsf sdf dsdsf sdfdsf dsfdsf dsf fdsdfsd fdsfdsf dfdsfdsfds  dsfsdf d f ds fdf df df dsfdsf dfdsf d      fdsdf dfs harsha"
                            ],
                            "_version_": 1508203924863058000
                        }
                    ],
                    "highlighting",
                    {
                        "nvPairs": [
                            "21",
                            {
                                "nvPairs": [
                                    "name",
                                    [
                                        "asd asda fsdfsdfds <em>harsha</em> sadaks asdasd sad fsddsf dsfdsf dsf sdf dsdsf sdfdsf dsfdsf dsf fdsdfsd fdsfdsf dfdsfdsfds  dsfsdf d f ds fdf df df dsfdsf dfdsf d      fdsdf dfs <em>harsha</em>"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        };

var highlight = {};

$.each(newresult._highlighting, function(i, hitem){
    var match = hitem.name[0].match(/<em>(.*?)<\/em>/);
  // var match = hitem.description[0].match(/elegant/g);
    console.log("match "+match);
    highlight[i] = match[1];


});
var res1 = newresult._highlighting;
var results;
var result;
for(var res2 in res1)
{
    var hlight = res1[res2].name;
    results= highlight[res2];

}

$.each(hlight, function(ix, items){
    var word = results;
    result = items.replace(new RegExp(word, 'g'),word);

});

//var res = newresult.response.nvPairs[5].nvPairs[1].nvPairs[1];
//var word ="harsha";
//var result = res[0].replace(new RegExp(word, 'g'), '<em>harsha</em>');






   $("body").append('<div>' + result + '</div>');



});
```

Comment: The question is too vague without sample HTML "a particular data field in a particular column" does not describe how you choose that data or column. Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CdyH/)

```
$("#coa_history_data tbody tr.data-in-table").each(function() {
  var $firstCell = $('td:eq(2)', this);
  var $secondCell = $('td:eq(3)', this);
  var $thirdCell = $('td:eq(4)', this);
  var $fourthCell = $('td:eq(5)', this);
if($firstCell.text() != $secondCell.text()){
   $firstCell.css('backgroundColor','yellow');
    $secondCell.css('backgroundColor','yellow');  
}
if($thirdCell.text() != $fourthCell.text()){
   $thirdCell.css('backgroundColor','orange');
    $fourthCell.css('backgroundColor','orange');  
}
```

});